# Problems with Ubuntu MATE 16.04.01 LTS and Acer Aspire ONE D150-1 Bk

Tags: boot, networking, suspend, shutdown

I installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.01 LTS on a netbook, Acer Aspire ONE D150-1 Bk and I have two issues:

1) When I turn off my netbook, the netbook doesn't turn off, but it goes to standby mode. I need to press the ON button, the PC restarts and again click on the icon to turn off the PC, and my netbook goes OFF. Same thing when I turn it ON, I press the ON button, and after the bios message, the PC goes to standby mode, I need to press again the ON button and only after this procedure, the PC turns ON, so what's the problem?

I also noticed that when I turn off my PC, the screen goes all black and it appears only a line that says something like `dev/sda1 clean, xxxxxx bytes, xxxx bytes` something like this. Is this a result of a `fsck`?, Can it be connected to my problem?

For this problem I try this "fix":

- I try with a `shutdown -h now` command and the PC turns OFF normally;
- Also checked my power management settings in `System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Power Management` and set all the options to `Never` or `Do Nothing`, but I have the same problem;
- In `System -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Power Management -> General` I set `When press the ON button -> Turn OFF the PC`. When I press the ON button, my PC goes OFF normally but why the PC behaves this way? What's the problem?

2) Sometimes when I turn on my PC the Wi-Fi card doesn't show any wireless network, so I need to open a terminal and issue the following command: `sudo service network-manager restart`. After this command, the Wi-Fi starts to work well, why I need to do this, why the Wi-Fi card sometimes doesn't show any wireless network?

For this Problem I try this "fix":

- Here is the output of the command `sudo systemctl status network-manager`, performed after switching on the PC and before restarting the service `network-manager`: https://thepb.in/p/76hErQzXPk1HV

Answer (score 0):

I solved these problems by updating the BIOS of my netbook to the latest version.

Comment: Great you have solved it! But please follow the rules of this site. Instead of adding SOLVED, mark your question accepted. This is possible after two days. https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Comment: If you cannot login to your original account, please follow https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts.